# How much chlorine gas can I safely put in my atmosphere?

Tags: environment, earth-like, atmosphere

I have a planet that I want to have a greenish atmosphere. I've heard in a few places that chlorine gas has the potential to make the atmosphere greenish, but also to kill humans. So, the question is, what percent of Earth's atmosphere (in nitrogen) can I replace with chlorine gas in my atmosphere without seriously damaging humans? Humans would have to be able to inhabit this planet without dying because of the gas.

Note - A less important side question, what color would the atmosphere look like if I added the maximum amount?

Comment: "what percent of Earth's atmosphere (in hydrogen) can I replace" What do you mean, "in hydrogen"?

Comment: Aaannnd, that now means what? You only want to replace the nitrogen portion of the atmosphere with chlorine?

Comment: @Samuel Oops, I meant Nitrogen. In case it's still unclear, earth has along the lines of 78% N2, 21% O2, and 1% a lot of other things. So what I am saying is do something like change it to 60% N2, 18% Cl2, 21% O2, and 1% everything else.

Comment: This seems like such a valid world building question, and yet the realist in me looks at your plan and thinks "stupid! stupid! stupid!"  I'm really glad you creative types aren't in charge of the gas mixture I have to breath on a daily basis!  The pollution is bad enough as is! =)

Comment: @CortAmmon I didn't really think about it until I posted the question.

Comment: Really, adding *chlorine gas* to make something green? ;) While we're making everything horrible, why not go all the way and add *chlorine trifluoride*? (Just read this hilarious post titled `Sand will not save you this time`, http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/02/26/sand_wont_save_you_this_time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**0.04% will kill you in about 30 minutes.**

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3136961/) on chlorine gas inhalation says:

> Concentrations of about 400 ppm and beyond are generally fatal over 30
>   minutes, and at 1,000 ppm and above, fatality ensues within only a few
>   minutes.

They cite safe workplace levels (6-hours of exposure) at 0.5 ppm (0.00005%).

It's unlikely you'll get the desired amount of green in the atmosphere using this method.

Comment: So the bottom line is that I can have 0.00005% of the total atmosphere. Hm, no wonder it's a trace gas.